# TimeoutException when using headless Chrome with selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation

When using headless Chrome, I'm seeing `org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException`, even after waiting 180 seconds with `WebDriverWait`.

Here's my code:

```java
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

options.addArguments("headless","--start-maximized","--enable-features=ReaderMode","--kiosk-printing","--disable-notifications","--disable-gpu");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("https://www.dinamani.com/"); 

driver.manage().window().maximize();

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(180));    

WebElement click = (WebElement)wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"srch-term\"]")));

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"srch-term\"]")).sendKeys("பொருநை போற்றுதும்");
```

How can I make my script work?

Comment: add a break point on wait.until line and remove headless. then check if the element is really present. Also post the HTML of the element.

Comment: it is present when in normal mode if i change into headless its not showing

Comment: oh, you don't click on search bar.

Comment: Fluent wait might work on this where you have to poll time to check the presence of an element and if present, then you can proceed to other activity.